# Fitting Intervals in two lines

Tags: algorithm

I'm a bit stuck on this problem:

> Given a list of n courses, where course i starts at Si and ends at Fi,
>   find an algorithm that fits the courses' schedule in 2 halls where as
>   each hall accommodates only one course at a time.

I thought about solving with the optimal solution for each hall,where you put the minimum Fi each time in the hall then remove all Si that start before the minimum Fi ,Keeping recursively till the courses end.then doing the optimal solution for hall two.
found out that optimal solution for each hall does not give the optimal solution for both together.

edit:

An optimal solution is a solution that fits the most courses in the two halls with the minimal time complexity

for example: List of courses:

> {(0,1], (0,5], (1,2], (2,3], (4,7], (5,6], (6,8]}

one hall should contain:

> {(0,1], (1,2], (2,3], (4,7]}

second one:

> {(0,5], (5,6], (6,8]}

However, my algorithm above starts fitting to the first hall;
when it gets to

```
hall1 = {(0,1], (1,2], (2,3]}
courses = {(0,5], (4,7], (5,6], (6,8]}
```

the algorithm chooses the earliest end time, adding `(5,6]`; the optimum solution requires (4,7] to be in hall1, with the other three courses in hall2.

Comment: Please explain what determines an "optimal" solution, as opposed to just any solution.  Find a solution, if one exists, is simple with a greedy algorithm, but it appears that's not what you want.

Comment: An optimal solution is a solution that fits the most courses in the two halls with the minimal time complexity. I updated the question thanks

Comment: Please post that example in your question, rather than just describing how your approach doesn't work for that one.

Comment: I added the example @Prune

Comment: You didn't finish the example: show how your first algorithm gets the wrong answer for that input.

Comment: my solution will give the following answer:
hall one:{(0,1]},{(1,2]},{(2,3]},{(5,6]},{(6,8]}
second hall:{(0,5]}

Comment: Got it; thanks -- but that should be edited into the question, too.  Also, the double punctuation -- both braces and parentheses -- hurts readability.

Answer (score 1):

Your attack is good, but too narrow: you need to do that with *all* halls, filling the one with the earliest available start time, rather than doing one hall entirely before you start the other.

Make a `hall_list` containing the available (start, end) times of each hall and the `sched` courses already allocated to that hall.

```
place_class (hall_list, course_list)
    start = earliest available start time of any hall
    if no such time, return present solution

    hall = the hall with that time
    course_ok = filter course_list for classes where S(i) <= start
    choose i from course_ok with the earliest F(i)

    append i to hall.sched
    remove i from course_list
    hall.start = F(i)

    place_course(hall_list, course_list)
```

---

This doesn't work for the example you posted; the same flaw is waiting, but it hits a fragmentation problem first: (1, 2] will be the first course put into hall 2.

**Value Refinement:**

As above, at every iteration, choose the earliest course with the highest value per hour.  A 1-hour class has value 1; the 5-hour class has value 1/5.

**Problem:**

This also fails; (0,5] is left for last, by which time there's no fit.

---

Best-fit refinement:

Choose the course with the earliest start time; in case of a tie, choose the earliest end time.

This happens to work for the given case.  In fact, if it's known that a solution exists to fit all classes, this will find the solution in linear time.  It's even easier if you iterate through courses sorted by start time.

*However*, if the optimal solution does *not* place all courses, then this can easily fail.  Add two more classes `(1,2], (2,3]`, and this algorithm will fail to see that they should replace `(0,5]` in hall 2.

---

**DEEPER ATTACK**

As @Marcin already pointed out in a deleted answer, this general case is *not* a simple problem.  To guarantee an optimal solution in any case, you need to make a deep search of the placement tree.  Write a recursive routine to try all possibilities.  Use dynamic programming: memoize your results, so that you don't make redundant calculations.  Key on the halls' remaining start times (sorted) and the remaining class list.

There *are* things you can do in pre-processing that might help real-world examples.  For instance, an isolated sequence of short classes can be fused into a common allocation with a higher value.  In your given example, you'd fuse `(0,1], (1,2], (2,3]` into `(0,3]`.  The finish time in (4,7] prevents you from (trivially) doing this with `(5, 6], (6, 8]`.

Does that help move you toward a solution?

Comment: this one does not work,imagine having three courses {(0,1]},{(1,2)} and {(0,2)} with two halls that starts with time 0.

Comment: Actually, it *does* work for that one, as the list is initially sorted by start time.  However, this answer still doesn't work for the example you edited into your post.